# Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 7Gen

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 20.04, thinkpad

I am trying to set up a Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 - preinstalled Windows 10 Pro on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7gen.

**Problem:**
I cannot find the bootable Ubuntu Live USB in the Boot Menu and therefore not setup a dual boot.

**The setup:**

- Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 7th
- BIOS MODE UEFI with BIOS Version LENOVO N2HET47W (1.30), 3/18/2020

**What have I done:**

- Created Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB using Rufus using Partition Scheme GPT, Target System UEFI(non CSM), File System FAT32
- Tried with disabled and not-disabled secure boot, disabled fast startup
- Confirmed the Ubuntu 20.04 Live USB works with a Lenovo Thinkpad E480 with UEFI and BIOS Version LENOVO R0PET63W (1.40), 03/01/2020

Help would be much appreciated ;)

Comment: UEFI update required for USB-C port issues 2017 thru 2019 models
ThinkPad models including the ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen to 7th Gen), X1 Yoga (2nd Gen to 4th Gen), and P-series 
https://www.cnet.com/news/is-your-thinkpads-usb-c-port-not-working-upgrade-its-firmware/
 & If SSD will need firmware update also.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the answers above were relevant for the simple solution of the question.

As it turned out the problem was that the USB HDD was EXCLUDED from the boot order and has to be added first.

In UEFI menu go to 'BOOT', select the USB HDD from 'Excluded from boot order' and hit '+'.
This adds the USB to the 'Boot priority order'. Then the USB can be selected to boot from at startup, when hitting F12 on the Thinkpad.

Then the rest of installing the DUAL BOOT worked flawlessly using this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have changed your Bios mode to AHCI in case it was on RST.
2. Secure boot enabled or disabled no problem it works.
3. Set your boot preference to USB EFI.
4. And Don't forget to make /boot/efi partition while installing ubuntu 20.04 for 
   dual boot purpose.

That's it you are good to go.